# (Grid) Stop the user from clicking past a certain amount of grid "Blocks"

Tags: c#, list, class

***Updated From My Previous Post***

As this is my first time working with lists, and my second month programming, please do not think that I'm an utter idiot.

My issue is trying to prevent the user from clicking (Which changes that spot to a new rectangle) 1 block in all directions past his/her previous clicked block.

My code so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Quoridor
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         private static List<RectangleAndPenBlack> recListBlack = new List
                            <RectangleAndPenBlack>();
         private static List<RectangleAndBrushRed> recListRed = new List<RectangleAndBrushRed>();
         private static List<RectangleAndBrushGreen> recListGreen = 
                             recListBlack.Cast<RectangleAndBrushGreen>().ToList();

         private static Size recSize = new Size(50, 50);

         private bool isFirstRectanglePlaced = false;

         private int previousIndex;
         private int rectanglesPlaced;

         RectangleAndBrushGreen recGreen = new RectangleAndBrushGreen();

         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();

             FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;

             for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
             {
                 for (int y = 0; y < 18; y++)
                 { 
                     Point recPoint = new Point(x * 50, y * 50);

                     recListBlack.Add(new RectangleAndPenBlack
                     {
                         blackRectangle = new Rectangle(recPoint, recSize),
                     });
                 }

                 Application.DoEvents();
             }
         }

         protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
         {
             base.OnPaint(e);

             foreach (RectangleAndPenBlack rpb in recListBlack)
             {
                 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(rpb.blackPen, rpb.blackRectangle);
             } 

             foreach (RectangleAndBrushRed rpr in recListRed)
             {
                 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(rpr.redBrush, rpr.redRectangle);
             }

             foreach (RectangleAndBrushGreen rpg in recListGreen)
             {
                 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(rpg.greenBrush, rpg.greenRectangle);
             }
         }

         private void overrideRectangle(MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             foreach (RectangleAndPenBlack rpb in recListBlack.ToList())
             {
                 if (rpb.blackRectangle.Contains(e.Location) && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                 {
                     recListBlack.Remove(rpb);

                     recListRed.Add(new RectangleAndBrushRed
                     {
                         redRectangle = new Rectangle(rpb.blackRectangle.Location, recSize)
                     });

                     isFirstRectanglePlaced = true;

                     Invalidate();
                 }

             }

             foreach (RectangleAndPenBlack rpb in recListBlack.ToList())                
             {               
                 if (rpb.blackRectangle.Contains(e.Location) && e.Button == MouseButtons.Right 
                                                             && rectanglesPlaced <= 1)
                 {
                     previousIndex = recListBlack.IndexOf(rpb);

                     recListBlack.Remove(rpb);

                     recListGreen.Add(new RectangleAndBrushGreen
                     {
                         greenRectangle = new Rectangle(rpb.blackRectangle.Location, recSize)
                     });

                     Invalidate();
                 }
                 else if (rpb.blackRectangle.Contains(e.Location) && e.Button == 
                                               MouseButtons.Right && rectanglesPlaced <= 1)
                 {
                     if (checkIfMoveIsValid(rpb, e))
                     {
                         previousIndex = recListBlack.IndexOf(rpb);

                         recListBlack.Remove(rpb);

                         recListGreen.Add(new RectangleAndBrushGreen
                         {
                             greenRectangle = new Rectangle(rpb.blackRectangle.Location, recSize)
                         });

                         Invalidate();
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     }
                 }
             } 
         }

         public Boolean checkIfMoveIsValid(RectangleAndPenBlack rpb, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             if ((rpb.blackRectangle.Location) == e.Location)
             {
                 return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }

         private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
             overrideRectangle(e);

             rectanglesPlaced += 1;
         }
     } 
 }
```

And the classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quoridor 
{
    class RectangleAndBrushRed
    {
        public Rectangle redRectangle { get; set; }
        public Brush redBrush = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quoridor
{
    public class RectangleAndPenBlack
    {
        public Rectangle blackRectangle { get; set; }
        public Pen blackPen = Pens.Black;       
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quoridor
{
    public class RectangleAndBrushGreen
    {
        public Rectangle greenRectangle { get; set; }
        public Brush greenBrush = Brushes.Green;             
    }
}
```

If you need clarification, feel free to ask! :D

Comment: Sometimes, there is such a thing as *too* much information. This is a wall of code askings "Why doesn't this work?" Can you remove pieces of code you know aren't affecting the problem (The pen/brush classes come to mind, but you know your code the best). Also, is this a repost? Is the other question still open? Reposting is highly discouraged here. Edit instead!

Comment: I don't know if the other question is open, but this is an updated version.

Comment: It looks like your other questions have answers, is this a duplicate or a new issue?

Comment: Ok no problems then (other than the wall of code). I'll attempt to parse through it. Hopefully someone can answer!